# TailwindCSS + Nuxt background image

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I am using TailwindCSS in a Nuxt project and I am trying to add a background image to a header element. The tailwindCSS official docs solution for this is the following : `<div class="bg-fixed ..." style="background-image: url(...)"></div>`

I have an images folder in the webpack assets folder where my bitcoin.jpg image lives.

I have tried using `<header class="bg-fixed" style="background-image: url(~assets/images/bitcoin.jpg)"`
This is not working, I have also tried classbinding, that doesn't work either. Anyone got an idea about a fix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (EDIT: This doesn't work, scroll down):

```
<header class="bg-fixed" style="background-image: url(~@/assets/images/bitcoin.jpg)"
```

The `~` tells webpack to treat the url as a module request, then you need to use a correct alias.  In nuxt, these are usually prefixed with `@`.

**EDIT**

I didn't realize that there's something strange going on under the hood with Webpack.  That syntax works with `src` attributes, but Webpack won't do the path resolution for `background-image`.

Here's the real fix:

```
<header class="bg-fixed" :style="{'background-image': `url(${require('@/assets/images/bitcoin.jpg')})`}"
```

By using `require`, you signal to Webpack to use the `file-loader` to create the proper module path, and replace that in the `url` function.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-mountain-zdw09?file=/pages/index.vue

Quote for reference:

> In order for Webpack to return the correct asset paths, you need to use require('./relative/path/to/file.jpg'), which will get processed by file-loader and returns the resolved URL

Page where the quote is from: https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html

Ref: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/646

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried that too, unfortunately that doesn't work either, I still get 'GET http://localhost:3000/~@/assets/images/bitcoin.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Christian.P I've added an update and a working example that addresses the problem, looks to be a limitation to how Vue's Webpack config is defined under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

package.json

```bash
"nuxt": "^3.0.0"
"@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.1.3"
```

1

```bash
<header class="bg-fixed bg-[url('assets/images/bitcoin.jpg')]"/>
```

2

```bash
<header class="bg-fixed" :style="{ backgroundImage: `url('assets/images/bitcoin.jpg')` }"/>
```

3

```bash
<header class="bg-fixed" :style="`background-image: url('assets/images/bitcoin.jpg')`"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The header hasn't got any content, nor height or width so it is not displayed. And you can't see the background.
A working solution would be :

```
<div class="bg-fixed w-full" style="background-image: url('/images/bitcoin.jpg'); min-height: 200px;" />
```

I added 100% width and 200px min-height.
And also, you seemed to miss the single quotes around the image path.

bg-fixed isn't quite the best solution, you should try **bg-cover** or **bg-contain** with
**bg-no-repeat**

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-size#class-reference

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to leave this here (as a self note maybe!).

You don't have to use require or any other package in this example.

I am also using a variable to get the image name (this can work in a v-for etc).

```
<script setup>
  let imageName = '1.png';
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div :class="['bg-[url(/images/'+imageName+')]']" class="w-[200px] h-[200px]"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

IMPORTANT NOTE : if you declare a path like I am doing in the example, then it means that the /images/ folder is inside public folder (public/images/1.png).