# Background image not displaying in a TailwindCSS + Nuxt project

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to display a background image in a Nuxt/Tailwind application. The image is in the `assets/images/` folder. This is my div =>

```
<div class="w-full h-405" style="background-image: url('~assets/images/my_image.png');">
  some text/string
</div>
```

The image doesn't show.
In my inspector I have

```
element.style {
    background-image: url(~assets/images/my_image.png);
}
```

and if I hover on the link `~assets/images/my_image.png` I see

```
Rendered size:  1 × 1 px
Rendered aspect ratio:  1∶1
File size:  43 B
Current source: http://localhost:3000/~assets/images/my_image.png
```

My guess is that the `Rendered size: 1 x 1 px` means the image isn't rendered. How can I display a background image without inserting that image in the `tailwind.config.js` file ??

Comment: Maybe try with `:style`?

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the image files from the `assets` folder and put them in the `static` folder. To use them in Nuxt, I called them like this

```
<div class="w-full h-405" style="background-image: url('/images/my_image.png');">
  some text/string
</div>
```

`images` is the folder containing my images in the `static` folder.

Comment: This will not be handled by Webpack tho.

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63064392) worked for me:

```
<div class="w-full h-405" :style="{'background-image': `url(${require('@/assets/images/my_image.png')})`}">
  some text/string
</div>
```

It seems that using `-assets/image.png` triggers Webpack for the `src:` attribute, but not for the `background-image:` attribute.

Comment: Hm, sure about this one. Webpack doesn't do such analytical things.

Answer (score 0):

This code is worked for me.Normal Url only work for online images.For local images, should use require.

```
<div
  class="h-72"
  :style="{
    'background-image': `url(${require('../static/assets/Rectangle.svg')})`,
  }"
></div>
```